# How can I get my regular expression to work for all of my sample data

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that captures the following sample data:

```
BEL  p1       QUEEN ST.WEST-SMARTEN   FL          DARNLEY BAY      F  09  1116  Race 3
BEL  p2       OUTSTAND-BOLD N'FLASHY   ON           WE’LL TALK      F  10  1116  Race 3
BEL  p3       KAHLUA BAY-CATRAIL   KY             GO OLIVIA GO      F  10  1116  Race 3
BEL  p4       FORTUNATE CHANCE-AMERICAN CHANCE   KYROSIE MY WAY      F  10  1116  Race 3
BEL  p5       ARBORESQUE-CURE THE BLUES   AR    TAYLOR JAGGER      F  10  1116  Race 3
BEL  p6       UNBRIDLED GLORY-UNBRIDLED   KYLOVE THE BREEDING      F  10  1116  Race 3
```

I have created a regular expression that has 9 capture groups:

1. Track Code (BEL)
2. Page number (p1)
3. Sire & Dam (QUENN ST.WEST-SMARTEN)
4. Foaling State/Country (FL)
5. Horse Name (DARNLEY BAY)
6. Horse Gender (F)
7. Year BorN (09)
8. Distance of Race (1116)
9. Race Number (Race 3)

Here is my regular expression:

```
^([A-Z]+)\s+(p[0-9]+)\s+([-'A-Z,.\s]+)\s+([A-Z]{1,3})\s+([A-Z\s']+)\s+([F|M])\s+([0-9]{1,2})\s+(.*)\s+(Race\s.*)$  /gm modifiers
```

Unfortunately, my expression is only working on the 1st and 5th rows of my sample data. I believe Row 2 fails because the regular expression is not matching either the Sire & Dam or the Horse's name.   The other rows that are not matched correctly seem to have something to do with the foaling state/country.  In some cases the State/Country field seems to be running into the Horse Name field so my regular expression is treating the sire/dam group as one  (combining sire/dam, foaling area and horse name).

Here is my regular expression and results on RegEx101: [MyRegular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/nU3iK3/1)

I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have on how I can improve my regular expression.

Comment: The second row fails because it contains the character `’` (`WE’LL TALK`) which isn’t covered by the regex. Either include it in the regex or replace it by `'`.

Comment: It could seem like these are tab separated - are they? If so you can simply use a tsv parser.

Comment: Do you know anything about the input structure? E.g. number of characters per field, etc. Looks like some of your input is muddled. There doesn't seem to be a delimiter between the state and horse name in "KYROSIE" or "KYLOVE THE BREEDING".

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because the apostrophe in the second row is `’`, not `'`. If you add that character into capturing group five, [all rows match](https://regex101.com/r/tO4oR9/1).

As one improvement, this isn't doing what you think it is:

```
([F|M])
```

This is matching either `F`, `|`, or `M`. You can change that by removing the `[]`:

```
(F|M)
```

I made a few changes that include getting rid of some of the character classes that you have where text can occur, and changing them to `.+`, since you don't want to have to list out every possible character there is for the fields. I also changed `[0-9]+` to just use `\d+`, which is the shorthand equivalent.

```
^([A-Z]+)\s+(p\d+)\s+(.+)\s+([A-Z]{1,3})\s+(.+)\s+(F|M)\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(.+)\s+(Race\s+\d+)$
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and improvements. You are correct that it is matching all five sample rows now, but it's also combining the Sire/Dam, Foaling State/Country and Horse name field.  Any thoughts for workarounds on that issue?

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor - Sure, it's probably because I used a greedy match instead of a lazy one. Change `.+` to `.+?` in the regex, then I think you should be good to go.